# Photos that won't show up

Tags: html, css, photo

I'm developing a website and when I have these 5 or 6 social icons only two will show up.

Using Firefox's built-in dev console it shows me two tags inside the `class=""` element, like this:

[image]

And when I look at the source code it only shows me that there is one tag inside the `class=""` element,
like this example:

[image]

And I only use CSS for positioning them, and not for any other here.

Comment: Are you using any plugins?

Comment: there is no plugins in any browser except the Adblock plus that I have removed the blocking of social icons

Comment: Are you running it through asp.net or anything like that?

Comment: I'm using XAMPP on the mac to show the PHP page

Comment: Check if the path for this photos is correct.

Comment: @Elem3nt4lSh0tZ, I edited your question to upload your images. The reason for this is that in these images need to stay viewable in the future, and if you self-host you'll have to keep self-hosting. If you upload, then you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import your CSS sheet into your html document by doing this:

```
<link href="LINKTOCSSFILE" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or are you using image files to load the photos?

EDIT:

Change height and width of the images from `32` to `32px`. First you have to add the style attribute by doing this:

```
<img src="https://www.logicaltrainers.com/gallery/HTML5CSS3.png" alt="" style="height: 32px; width: 32px">
```

[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa345/)

Comment: It's already linked, if you look at the `class=""` element in this picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ni1jc7wrqjwkb9p/Firefox%20Webdevelopment%20tool.png and compare the same `class=""` element in this picture https://www.dropbox.com/s/t69ozfgf9ljenza/The%20real%20code.png

Comment: Here's the source code from the `<head>` tag in HTML:
`<head>
        <title><?php echo $line[0]; ?></title>
        <link href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>`

Comment: Updated my thread, you have to add the style attribute to your img element. see the jsFiddle